# Are there two separate JVM instances created when both hibernate and spring are used in an enterprise application?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, jvm

Are there two separate JVM instances created when both hibernate and spring are used in an enterprise application? If hibernate and spring class are used inside eclipse, will they use eclipse's jvm instance to load their classes also? Does any of the spring or hibernate classes contain main method in order to create a jvm instance? If there is no main class in a jar, how are the classes loaded to memory or how can we create a separate JVM instance for them?

Comment: The answer to all questions is "No". Regarding your last question: Why? Your application (or the application server) will contain the main method and load all necessary classes in memory. No need for Hibernate or Spring to do this on their own.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a separate JVM instance for Hibernate and for spring when they are used together in an application?

No.

> If hibernate and spring class are used inside eclipse, will they use eclipse's jvm instance to load their classes also?

It depends how you launch the app from within Eclipse.  But the answer is probably No.  (And with good reason.)

> Does any of the spring or hibernate classes contain main method in order to create a jvm instance?

Hibernate, No.  Spring, maybe.  It depends on >>how<< you are using Spring.

- If you are using Spring Boot, then somewhere within the Spring codebase there will probably be a `main` method.
- If you are using classic Spring within a webcontainer (e.g. Tomcat, Jetty, etc), then the `main` method is provided by the container.

> If there is no main class in a jar, how are the classes loaded to memory or how can we create a separate JVM instance for them?

In general, the answer is that the JAR (or WAR) is used by something else that knows how to load and start "your" code.  That something else could be a normal Java program that is run using the `java` command, and that has its own `main` method, or it could be a custom launcher (e.g. written in C / C++) that starts an embedded JVM and calls a custom "entry point" method in your Java code to get things started.  Either way, the JVM takes care of the code loading.

The fact that you have multiple JARs doesn't imply that you would or should create separate JVMs for them.  It depends on the nature of the software in the JARs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your enterprise application jar file several times using "java" command line, each created instance will run in a  seperate  JVM n